# Temp table to get the value from a Table using UNION

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I HAVE a table name **Book , Statement, Chapter, Section, Post.** 
The Post table has a Column name **DisplayMessage** which i need to get a distinct record of.

```
2 ways it can be mapped in UI 

First way is 
Book , Statement, Chapter, Section, Post.
OR 
Book , Statement,Chapter, Post. (Post has the Column "Message")
```

As you can see it depends upon the user if he wants to include the **TABLE  Section** to be mapped in the UI for that CHAPTER.

Here is the PRoc that i wrote

```
@Temptable TABLE 
(
PK_Chapter   INT
ChapterName  NVARCHAR
SectionName  NVARCHAR
PostName     NVARCHAR
Message      NVARCHAR(526)
)
Insert into @Temptable
Select Distinct
PK_Chapter
ChapterName
SectionName
PostName 
Message 
From Book b
INNER JOIN Chapter c ON b.PK_Book    = c.FK_Book    --Chapter
INNER JOIN Section s ON c.PK_Chapter = s.FK_Chapter --Section
INNER JOIN Post p    ON s.PK_Section = p.FK_Section --Post
UNION 
Select Distinct
PK_Chapter
ChapterName
SectionName
PostName 
Message 
From Book b                                         -- Book
INNER JOIN Chapter c ON b.PK_Book    = c.FK_Book    --Chapter
INNER JOIN Post p    ON c.PK_Chapter=  p.FK_Chapter --Post
Select * from @Temptable
```

It is working but i want to have a better way of thinking and writing a proc using temptable. 
I need to get from A to D wher D has the Value . In simple terms i can use A,B,C,D.VALUE (which need to be DISTINCT )
But i have the option not to use C 
I can also go A,B,D.VALUE
Thanks for having a look .